# Prevent automatic generation of model specs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

When I issue this command

```
rails generate model  page title:string
```

I get

```
  invoke  active_record
   create    db/migrate/20140507190336_create_pages.rb
   create    app/models/page.rb
   invoke    rspec
   create      spec/models/page_spec.rb
```

Sometimes, we dont want tests.
How can I tell the rails generate commmand to skip
model tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this instead:

```
rails generate model  page title:string --no-test-framework
```

This makes the model generator skip creating the rSpec files.